# Include pdf files in new version of Sierra

Tags: beamer, graphics, mac, texshop

With the new version of Sierra for Mac, TeXSHop crashes when the pdf
file is created. Adding '% !TEX TS-program = latex' at the top of the
file, as suggested in a previous post, works fine iff my figures are "eps" files. I still have not figured out how to include "pdf" files in a beamer file with the new version of Sierra. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which one is "a previous post"?  Please provide a link.  I don't have a Mac, so I can't try myself, but to me it seems you are providing too little information to reproduce.  For example, which versions of the programs are you using?  Does it happen for all input files or only for particular ones?  Please write a guide to unambiguously reproduce your problem with all the steps from installation to failure.

Comment: Right now I'm voting to close as unclear. Please ping me when you clarified your post, so I can retract my vote.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: There is a known bug in the pdf toolkit in MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 (was also in 10.12.4, not sure about earlier). TeXShop uses the same engine that Preview uses. Acrobat's code base is separate so it should be able to open your PDF files. I suggested a temporary fix at [TexShop freezes with large pdf files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/366197/4301). This problem does not seem related to the size of the PDF file -- I genarate a 3,500 page pdf file daily and it opens just fine in TeXShop. My smaller files with figures does crash TeXShop sometime and is VERY slow in rendering the PDF.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/362683/36296